# Integral of DiracDelta giving an unusual answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been getting a number of seemingly inconsistent solutions to integrals of Dirac delta functions in which the integrand evaluates to `DiracDelta[0]` at one of the bounds. A minimal example is the following:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[a - x] , {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> {a, b} ∈ Reals]
```

Which evaluates to

```
1 + DiscreteDelta[b] - 2 HeavisideTheta[a - b] + HeavisideTheta[a - b, -a + b]
```

Whereas I would have expected the much simpler answer:

```
HeavisideTheta[a - b] - HeavisideTheta[0]
```

In particular, I cannot understand how $b=0$ should be a special case. (The result should be invariant under `a -> a + c`, `b -> b + c`). I am running *Mathematica 10.0*. Is this an error, or am I missing something subtle?

Comment: The result seems to incorrect, more specific command `Integrate[DiracDelta[a - x], {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> a < b]` gives `HeavisideTheta[0]`. But the question itself is incorrect, since delta-function is not well-defined on discontinuous function and Mma is asked about the application of $\delta[a-x]$  on the step `HeavisideTheta[a-x]`.

Comment: Yes, it gives the correct answer if we assume `a>b`. However, I would like it to give the correct answer for `a>=b`. Ideally, I would figure out a way to make it behave as such, or else understand why doing so would lead to an inconsistency.

Comment: It's not. For `Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, 1}]` Mma gives $\delta (0)$.  But the value of $\int_0^1 \delta (x) \, dx$ is not defied. So what do you call the correct evaluation of the this integral? In the standard definition delta-function is not supposed to act on discontinuous functions.

Comment: I think you mean it gives $\theta(0)$. The main problem is that Mma gives one answer for the integral from $0$ to $1$, but a different answer if we evaluate it for general $a$ and $b$, and then substitute $a->0$, $b->1$. I would like Mma to return a consistent answer, or know for sure that this is a bug and figure out how to avoid it.

Comment: Also, $\int_0^1 \delta(x)dx$ is defined in many formalisms, for instance when one treats $\delta$ as the limit of a Gaussian. In fact, $\theta(x)$ is often defined to be the integral of $\delta$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). This is consistent with the answer I gave in the post, and the answer Mma gives from $\int_0^1 \delta(x)dx$

Comment: Seems to be a bug. In V9 this produces the same answer. 

This 

`Integrate[DiracDelta[a - x], {x, a - 1, b}, Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals] -  Integrate[DiracDelta[a - x], {x, a - 1, a},   Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals]`

gives $\theta (b-a)-\theta (0)$.

Comment: I submitted the issue to Mathematica, and they confirmed it is a bug. No word on if they have fixed it so far.

Comment: Encyclopedia of Mathematics  (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function ) states the integral under consideration makes no sense.

Comment: These integrals make perfect sense if we take DiracDelta to be a normalized Gaussian distribution (or similar) in the limit of zero variance, as is almost always the case in physics. But this is beside the point. The issue is that Mathematica's treatment of DiracDelta appears to be internally inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

MMa 11.3 gives the same result using the original assumptions, but using slightly different assumptions:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[a - x], {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b > a]
(*HeavisideTheta[0]*)
```

Which if you set

```
% /. HeavisideTheta[0] -> 1
(*1*)
```

I would call that correct.

Comment: That was discussed in this forum several times. Up to traditional math the integral under consideration has no sense (eg see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: A lot of electrodynamics problems couldn't be solved if that integral makes no sense.  The DiracDelta spike is at `x = a`, the limits of integration include `x = a`, and in physics, the integral evaluates to `1`.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is an aside. The current implementation of DiracDelta confuses DiracDelta as a distribution with the atomic measure concentrated at the origin (see the cited Wiki article).

Comment: There is nothing in that article that says this integral has no sense.  With real numbers, the integral of a standalone `DiracDelta` function is either `0` or `1` depending on whether the spike is included in the limits of integration.  The only question is when the spike is at one of the integration limits.  The value then depends on the context of the problem and the user gets to choose.  MMa gives the user a choice by returning `HeavisideTheta[0]` which he can set to `0` or `1` as desired.

Comment: You wrote "There is nothing in that article that says this integral has no sense". See the Definitions section to this end, in particular, "This is merely a heuristic characterization. The Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense as no function defined on the real numbers has these properties.[17] The Dirac delta function can be rigorously defined either as a distribution or as a measure". It is not enough to read the first three lines of the article.

Comment: I like J. D. Jackson's definition from his Classical Electrodynamics book the best. `Integrate[DiracDelta[x - a] = 1` if the region of integration includes `x = a` and is zero otherwise. That definition has been serving me well since the early 1970's.  While the delta function may not be a true function, its integral is always well defined.

Comment: Encyclopedia of Mathematics  (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function ) states the integral under consideration makes no sense.

Comment: @user64494.  When $f(x) = 1$, then the very first formula in that article says the integral is $1$.  Pretty much all integrals of Delta functions make sense.  I stand by my previous comments, and in the case of Jackson's definition, your article is in agreement.

Comment: Maybe you should read Jackson rather than wikipedia.